# Incorrect algorithm to find minimum number of swaps required to sort an array

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, swap

I used this algorithm to find minimum number of swaps required but this does not give correct result for all test cases. Can anyone help me figuring out what are the cases for which this does not give correct correct result and why.

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1 or len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    e = min(arr)
    if e == arr[0]:
        return 0 + minimumSwaps(arr[1:])
    else:
        k = arr.index(e)
        arr[0], arr[k]  =  e, arr[0]   # or use swap(arr, 0, k)
        return 1 + minimumSwaps(arr[1:])
```

Comment: _You_ got the testcases - run the code and look which it solves and which not ?

Comment: Don't Know what are the test cases.

Comment: Kindly change spelling of short to sort. It is misleading.

Comment: Please provide the test cases. We don't know what they are.

Comment: Even I don't know that. If I know I can figure it out.

Comment: I'm confused. You mentioned that the algorithm "does not give correct result for all test cases.". How do you know this if you don't have at least one test case that gave an incorrect result when you ran it?

Comment: @Xukrao there's probably an online automated judge somewhere.

Comment: Here's your failing test case: `[1,0,0]`.

Comment: It is given that all elements are unique.

Comment: For all unique numbers the program looks correct, but it's very inefficient. Perhaps it's running out of time or memory.